# How can I exceed the 60% Memory Limit of IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, cache

Pardon if this is more stackoverflow vs. serverfault.  It seems to be on the border.

We have an application that caches a large amount of product data for an e-commerce application using ASP.NET caching.  This is a dictionary object with 65K elements, and our calculations put the object's size at ~10GB.
Problem:

1. The amount of memory the object consumes seems to be far in excess of our 10GB calculation.
2. **BIGGEST CONCERN:**  We can't seem to use over 60% of the 32GB in the server.

**What we've tried so far:**

In machine.config/system.web (sf doesn't allow the tags, pardon the formatting):

```
processModel autoConfig="true" memoryLimit="80"
```

In web.config/system.web/caching/cache (sf doesn't allow the tags, pardon the formatting):

```
 privateBytesLimit = "20000000000" (and 0, the default of course)
 percentagePhysicalMemoryUsedLimit = "90"
```

**Environment:**
Windows 2008R2 x64
32GB RAM
IIS7

Nothing seems to allow us to exceed the 60% value.

Comment: The screenshot didn't seem to make it.

Comment: In case anyone else runs upon this, looks like worker processes needs to be restarted after the processModel element is changed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1(v=VS.100).aspx